# Cannot pass an argument from ".bat" file to python script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, argv

I am trying to run a python script from my .bat file but I cannot pass the arguments. Please find my code below:

> .bat File

```
set fileDestination = "\home\a\.."
set fileLocation = "\home\b\.."
set fileName = "myFile.xlsx"

"C:\Swdtools\Python3.6.3 X64\Python" fileTransfer.py %fileDestination% %fileLocation% %fileName%
```

> fileTransfer.py

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[2])
```

The above print statement gives me

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `print(sys.argc)` should provide some details.

Comment: Get rid of the spaces around your `=` in your `set` statements.

Comment: Do you really want quotes in the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space between your variable name and the equal sign becomes part of the name and the space after becomes part of the value. Get rid of the white space:

```
set fileDestination="\home\a\.."
set fileLocation="\home\b\.."
set fileName="myFile.xlsx"
```

Comment: oh wow, I totally forgot about that. Thank you very much !!